# How to plot multiple 3D plots on the same graphic

Tags: plotting

This is the code that I was able to make

```
h[x_]:= x^2; a = 1; b = 5; n = 5; dx = b-a/n;
```

Those are my parameters

```
Table[ParametricPlot3D[{(a + i*dx) Cos[t], (a + i*dx) Sin[t], h},
 {t, 0, 2Pi}, {h, 0, h[a + i*dx]}], {i, 1, n}]
```

But I can't manage to plot them on the same graphic, I am trying to use the `DiscretePlot3D` function but I need more input for my code, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
DiscretePlot[[Table[ParametricPlot3D[{(a + i*dx) Cos[t],(a + i*dx) Sin[t], h},
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {h, 0, h[a + i*dx]}], {i, 1, n}]], {Table, 1, n}]
```

Some help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your code has a syntax error, with the second bracket after `DiscretePlot`.

Comment: How about using `GraphicsGrid[Table[...]]`?

Comment: `Rasterize[
 GraphicsRow[
  Table[ParametricPlot3D[{(a + i*dx) Cos[t], (a + i*dx) Sin[t], 
     h}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {h, 0, h[a + i*dx]}], {i, 1, n}]], 
 ImageSize -> 800, ImageResolution -> 1200]`

Answer (score 5):

```
f[a_, b_, n_, s_] := # {Cos@t, Sin@t, s #} &@(a + #*(b - a/n)) & /@  Range@n

p[a_, b_, n_] := ParametricPlot3D[f[a, b, n, s], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {s, 0, 1},
                         PlotRange -> b n {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, b n}}, 
                         PlotStyle -> ({Opacity[# /10 ], Hue[#]} & /@ (n/Range@n)), 
                         Mesh -> None, Evaluated -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]

p[1,5,5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
p[1,5,10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what you mean by "on the same graphic", so here's a few guesses.

```
cylinderlist = 
 Table[ParametricPlot3D[{(a + i*dx) Cos[t], (a + i*dx) Sin[t], h}, {t,
     0, 2 Pi}, {h, 0, h[a + i*dx]}, PlotPoints -> 100], {i, n}]
```

Show them all in a row,

```
Grid[{cylinderlist}]
```

[image]

Or perhaps laid over each other, on the same coordinate system

```
Show[Reverse@cylinderlist]
```

But there you can only see the outer one, but you can restrict the `PlotRange` to show them all

```
Show[Reverse@cylinderlist, PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 30}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Show@
 Table[
   ParametricPlot3D[
    {(a + i*dx) Cos[t], (a + i*dx) Sin[t], h}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {h, 0, h[a + i*dx]},
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {-30, 30}, {0, 600}},
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> None
   ],
   {i, 1, n}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

```
GraphicsRow[Table[ParametricPlot3D[{(a + i*dx) Cos[t], (a + i*dx) Sin[t], h}, 

{t, 0, 2 Pi}, {h, 0, h[a + i*dx]}], {i, 1, n}]]
```

or, use `GraphicsGrid[]` for more complex layouts [(reference)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGrid.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it this, that you need?

```
 h[x_] := x^2; a = 1; b = 5; n = 5; dx = b - a/n;
Show@Table[
  ParametricPlot3D[{(a + i*dx) Cos[t], (a + i*dx) Sin[t], h}, {t, 0, 
    2 Pi}, {h, 0, h[a + i*dx]}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3], 
   PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {-30, 30}, {0, 650}}, 
   ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"], {i, 1, n}]
```

giving
[image]

May be, it will be better visible like this:

```
 Show@Table[
  ParametricPlot3D[{(a + i*dx) Cos[t], (a + i*dx) Sin[t], h}, {t, 0, 
    2 Pi}, {h, 0, h[a + i*dx]}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {-30, 0}, {0, 650}}, 
   ColorFunction -> "LakeColors", ViewPoint -> {-30, 5, 60}], {i, 1, 
   n}]
```

you should see this:

[image]

Have fun!